# gather all links to *.txt files

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to retrieve all the links to text files in an HTML document, I don't know what the best way to do this is but, I have tried the following in ruby...

```
line.scan(/<a href="([\w+:\/.-]*.txt)/)
```

but I am not sure if this expression covers all possible links pointing to text file, I am wondering if there are some built-in regular expressions for this? or if anyone knows of a better way to retrieve all links to a text file in a huge webpage.

Comment: Use a DOM parser to gather all of the links, then go through the array of all links using a regular expression to find those ending in `.txt`. Don't use one regular expression to do both jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will walk through the HTML and find all hrefs with a '.txt' extension:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <head><title>foo</title></head>
  <body>
    <a href="file.txt">text file</a>
    <a href="file.jpg">jpg file</a>
    <a href="file2.txt">text file 2</a>
  </body>
</html>
EOT
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
puts doc.search('a').select { |n| n['href'][/\.txt$/] }.map{ |n| n['href'] }

> file.txt
> file2.txt
```

It's using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to parse the content, which really is a lot more bullet-proof than trying to use regex.

Comment: I am trying to install nokogiri but I get an error:

test21.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)
 from test21.rb:1

Yet I have actually installed the gem: gem list | grep nokogiri
nokogiri (1.4.4)

Comment: Are you on Ruby < 1.9? If so, you have to use `require 'rubygems'` before you require any gems. Ruby > 1.9 does that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (captures all txt files, not just links):

```
html.scan(/[^\s"']+\.txt/)
```

To capture links to text files only:

```
html.scan(/<a [^<>\n]*?href=["']([^\s"']+\.txt)["'][^<>\n]*?>.*?<\/a>/m)
```

Comment: What if the document contains the line `example.txt` that isn't actually a link?

Comment: If the HTML `<a>` tags were split across two lines it wouldn't work at all. That's why regex are so fragile.